# Manually assign an IP address won't take effect unless reboot

Tags: networking

Environment: Ubuntu Server 16.04

network-manager: not installed

Interface need to be change: enp0s9

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto enp0s9
iface enp0s9 inet static
    address 192.168.10.50
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I'd like to change the IP address of enp0s9 so I go through the interfaces file, modify the address line.

However, whatever how I restart/reload the enp0s9, the ip address still remain the old one. Only reboot the server can refresh the ip address.

syslog

```
Dec 26 11:55:02 localhost kernel: [   88.763677] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s9: link is not ready
Dec 26 11:55:02 localhost kernel: [   88.765633] e1000: enp0s9 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
Dec 26 11:55:02 localhost kernel: [   88.765981] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s9: link becomes ready
Dec 26 11:55:02 localhost systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Dec 26 11:55:02 localhost systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should try setting the ip "on the go" *(doesn't persist on reboot)* directly with *ifconfig* issuing `sudo ifconfig enp0s9 192.168.10.50 netmask 255.255.255.0`.

Also you can try *flushing current config* with `sudo ip addr flush enp0s9` and try again, if you still experince problems changing the ip *(maybe related to dhcp if it was initially active)*.

To setup the network interface vía `/etc/network/interfaces` I will add at least the "network" config (try to fill all fields and check logs), take this as example *(i'm using it on my personal home server)*:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary (wan & lan) network interface
auto enp1s7
iface enp1s7 inet static
        address 192.168.10.50
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.10.0
        gateway 192.168.10.1
        broadcast 192.168.10.255
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4

# The second (lan only) network interface
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

To restart the networking service use `sudo systemctl restart networking.service` or `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`.
I prefer using the first *(systemd way)*, and also using `sudo systemctl status networking.service` or `journalctl -xe` in case of error, which feel more comfortable for me instead of looking for something directly into *syslog (personal preference)*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `ip addr flush` did the trick. Thanks Bro!

Comment: Glad to read it solved you problem!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your question is but I'm guessing you want to change the settings without rebooting witch you can do by using the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: I think it would be advisable to start feeling comfortable in a more systemd way, with: `sudo systemctl restart networking.service` we have same results.

Comment: Hi Dam30n and @dgonzalez, actually I have already tried these two ways. So I mentioned in the post: I tried to restart/reload the network interface but nothing actually changed.

Comment: I also tried the combination of "ifdown" and "ifup", but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

For this command to work properly
type : vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
and then puts (managed=true).